# Fragments Vs. Activities and where certain methods go

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

I have been making the transition from activities to activities and fragments but I am getting a little confused about how much functionality should go in the activity and how much in the fragment. My initial thought was that the activity simply loaded a fragment (and many examples online work this way). This is fine, but what happens when things get more complicated? Here is a scenario:

You have an activity that loads two fragments, but only one is showing. After clicking a button, the first fragment is hidden and the second shows. Easy enough.

Now, what about if some button on the second fragment needs to call another activity with it's own fragments? Where should the callbacks go for the button listener, in the activity or the fragment? Where should the new activity be launched from? What about if the second fragment needs to call a content provider or a service? Where should that go? What about onActivityResult?

I kind of feel that anything that crosses an activity boundary (starting new activities, getting results etc) should probably go in to the activity, but this is forcing me to bind my activity to my fragments pretty heavily with callbacks, so now I don't know. I am starting to think now that activities should ONLY handle loading and switching fragments to keep them separate, and the inter-process and inter-activity (and even inter-fragment) calls should all happen within fragments.

EDIT: I assume retaining state on an orientation change would probably play into this decision as well!

Comment: This would be a better question if you provided a code sample specifically illustrating the issue you are having the most trouble with.

Comment: This sounds like an opinion based question...

Comment: I think this is more a question to understand the why and when use fragments...

Answer (score 0):

You can start Activity even Activity for result from Fragment. And also you can receive onActivityResult call in fragment. But remember, to get result from activity in fragment, in Activity you have implement onActivityResult method like this.

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
   super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Otherwise result won't get to fragment. Parameter requestCode can be used to differ result from various startActivityForResult calls.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't think that actually answered my question.

Answer (score 0):

I have discovered a very helpful site. It answers my questions and has a lot of information about Fragments and Activities and how they should relate:

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html